# Angular 5 - Update a form using debounceTime except an input if its pattern is not respected

Tags: angular5, angular-material2

I have a form with 8 input.
No input is required. Just one input with a pattern and a mat-error.
I update my form using debounceTime.
Here is my html:

```
<form #formCard="ngForm" id="formCard">
<mat-form-field class="col-12">
        <input matInput 
    placeholder="{{ 'POSITION' | translate }}"
        type="text"
        name="position"
        [(ngModel)]="user.position"
    >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="col-12">
        <input matInput
        placeholder="{{ 'ADDRESS' | translate }}"
        type="address"
        name="address"
        [(ngModel)]="user.location.address"
    >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="col-12">
        <input matInput
        placeholder="{{ 'CITY' | translate }}"
        type="text"
        name="city"
        [(ngModel)]="user.location.city"
    >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="col-12">
        <input matInput
        placeholder="{{ 'POST_CODE' | translate }}"
        type="text"
        name="postal_code"
        [(ngModel)]="user.location.postal_code"
    >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="col-12">
        <input matInput
        placeholder="{{ 'COUNTRY' | translate }}"
        type="text"
        name="country"
        [(ngModel)]="user.location.country"
    >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="col-12">
        <input matInput
        placeholder="{{ 'CONTACT_EMAIL' | translate }}"
        type="text"
        name="contact_email"
        [(ngModel)]="user.contact_email"
        pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-.+]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}"
    >
        <mat-error>{{ 'REQUIRED_VALID_EMAIL' | translate }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="col-12">
        <input matInput
        placeholder="{{ 'CELLPHONE' | translate }}"
        type="text"
        name="cell_phone_number"
        [(ngModel)]="user.cell_phone_number"
    >
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is my component

```
export class VcardComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('formVcard') formVcard: any;

public ngOnInit() {
        this.user = this._user.getCurrentUser();
        if (!this.user.location) {
            this.user.location = new Location();
        }
        this.formVcard.valueChanges
              .pipe(debounceTime(500),distinctUntilChanged())
                          .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
                          .subscribe(res => {
            if (this.init == true) {
                this.updateUser(this.user);

            } else {
                this.init = true
            }
        });
}

public updateUser(user) {
        this.user = user;
        this._user.updateUser(this.user).takeWhile(() => this.alive).subscribe(res => {
                res = this.user;
        },error => {
            this._toasterService.pop('error', this._translate.instant("ERROR"))
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

}

I want to be able to update my form using debounceTime without the value of my input if my validator is not respected and with it if validator is respedted. How can i update my form, maybe with `focusout` without splitting it?
Thx a lot :)

Comment: What do you mean by "without splitting it?" Your code doesn't update the form - it updates the "user" after the form is updated. The form is updated by input changes which update the control models. You can change when that happens using `[ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"`.

Comment: By 'splitting', I meant to say is that I have to do 2 forms? 2 use cases: 1) If a change is made on the other inputs of the form but the email_contact input does not fulfill its conditions, the user is updated with debounceTime without updating the value of the input email_contact ; 2) If a change is made to the other inputs of the form and the input email_contact fulfills its conditions, the user is fully updated (always with debounceTime).

Comment: You already know this if you are using a validator - check if the form status is valid or invalid, and take the appropriate update action.